# Word for a parent whose children have all died

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

I know there have been other questions asked that are similar, but I want to know about the specific case where a person has had a child or children, but all have passed on.

Is there an accepted word or term for a person in this situation?

Comment: I found a website (parphent.com) that coined the term "parphent" in April 2013. It doesn't seem to have caught on though.

Comment: Found another website (http://today.duke.edu/2009/05/holloway_oped.html) that suggested "vilomah" although it appears to be a parent who has lost a child, not necessarily all their children.

Comment: @tchrist, although close, that is not exactly what I'm asking. I want a term for a parent that has lost *all* of his/her children.

Comment: You don’t get a word: you get words. Language is about combining words in infinitely many ways to represent complex concepts.  Even if you had a “word”, nobody would know what you were talking about and so it would be completely useless.

Comment: 'John, a widower *bereaved of all three of his children* found new happiness when he met Jill'.

Comment: @tchrist, I'm OK if there is no such word, just curious if one existed, since I need a short way to reference this case at work. And words do spring up from nowhere to replace a string of words that represent complex concepts, like [selfie](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/selfie) or twerking (ugh).